# Selenium Python find element by name doesn't work

Tags: python, html, selenium, testing, pycharm

I'm testing the web form with several fields using a PyCharm and Selenium web driver.

There are a two similar DIVs on the webpage for a phone and e-mail:

```html
<div class="popup-subscribe-new__content">
                        <div class="field field_type_email js-field-custom-email js-field">
                            <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="field__input js-field-input js-inputmask-phone" pattern="^[0-9\+\-\( \)]+$" data-trim="true" pattern-flags="i">
                            <div class="field__error">Enter the phone number</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and

```html
<div class="popup-subscribe-new__content">
                    <div class="field field_type_email js-field-custom-email js-field">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="field__input js-field-input" pattern="^([A-Za-z0-9_\.\+\-])+@([A-Za-z0-9_\.\-])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$" data-trim="true">
                        <div class="field__error">Enter the e-mail</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

in my test I using  **phone_field = driver.find_element_by_name('phone')** for the phone search
and  **email_field = driver.find_element_by_name('email')** for the e-mail search

As the result, the test successfully found the phone field but after trying to find the email field the PyCharp answered with **ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible**

Where was I wrong?
Thank you,
Eugene

Comment: Check whether `len(driver.find_elements_by_name('phone'))` returns `1` or more. If more- try different locator

Comment: @Andersson it returns 1 in my case

Comment: why do you have phone_field  as variable name for both the web elements ?

Comment: @Andersson but  len_email = len(driver.find_elements_by_name('email')) returns 5

Comment: @cruisepandey oh, just typo, already fixed the question, there are email_field = driver.find_element_by_name('email')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30) 

phone_field = driver.find_element_by_name('phone')  
phone_field.send_keys('some phone number')
email_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class*='js-field-custom-email']>input[name='email']')))  

email_field.send_keys("""some@email.com"""")
```

make sure to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait until element will be visible like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
email_field = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
```

More information about `waits` can be found in the documentation [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).